# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence in Django

Tags: python, django

I keep getting the following Django error:

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

when I do `./manage.py runserver`

Here is the full stack trace:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x109183ae8>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>
> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>
> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>
> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>
> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 114, in check_models_permissions
>       max_builtin_permission_name_length = max(len(name) for name in builtin_permissions.values())
>
> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

What is the problem here? This is the only django project where I have this error.

Comment: Yes but I what does that even mean. What are builtin_permissions? Are they in database? Are they in settings?

Comment: [Django is (was) yet again broken.](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4e64e3bb6e96a50b057bc1144fba3efdee7dfc10). Update your Django.

Comment: Wow. This was one thing that didn't come to me earlier. I just added version 1.9.8 to my requirements.txt. 1.10 is broken

Comment: @Sevanteri - You might want to write that as an answer

Comment: I am getting the same error when running a Django 1.10 site. Were you able to fix this?